# Управление runtime environment в yandex cloud functions

Tags: python, yandex-cloud

Хочу написать навык для Алисы. Так как собственного сервера у меня нет, полез в Yandex Cloud Functions. Возник такой вопрос, на который так нигде и не смог найти ответа. Если мне нужен какой-то сторонний питонский пакет для моей функции, который требует отдельной установки через pip, как его поставить в среду выполнения функции? Пытался прямо в коде через os.system(), но это не сработало. Буду очень благодарен за совет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знакомые, работающие с Я.Облаком, подсказывают — нужно все зависимости, которых нет в окружении функции, собрать в один пакет, вместе с функцией и передать этот архив в сервис.
Если размер будет большой, то можно использовать местный S3, [тут описано как](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/functions/quickstart/function-quickstart#create-py-version).

Answer (score 1):

С сегодняшнего дня можно попробовать новый сервис на базе Cloud Functions — Serverless Containers (https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/serverless-containers/) — там можно собрать зависимости в контейнер самостоятельно и вызывать контейнер также как функцию.

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент, сервис Cloud Functions может автоматически устанавливать зависимости перечисленные в файле requirements.txt.

Подробнее по этой ссылке - https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/functions/lang/python/dependencies